# Assign size to image in Google Slides

Tags: google-slides

I would like to assign the size of an image in Google Slides.  I don't want to do it with the mouse because it is not letting me put the size I really want.  I want to enter a number and that the software respects the number I enter, like in Microsoft Power Point.  Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Google Slides does not yet allow you to specify an exact size for an image.

One workaround I've used successfully is to

1. Create a separate, blank drawing in Google Drawings.
2. Within Drawings, select File -> Page Setup... from the menu and set the page size to the exact size you want your image to be in Slides. (Note you can specify the size in either print units or pixels.)
3. Insert the image into the drawing and, if necessary, resize it so it fills the page.
4. Copy the image from Drawings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and paste it into Slides (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

You should find Slides retains the size of the image, and now you have it in your presentation at the exact size you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

1. Click on the pictures
2. Click on format options
3. Change the width and height so that all pictures have the same dimensions.
4. Done

Answer (score 4):

Another method I used is **Guides**.

1. Enable **Guides**. This option is found under View -> Guides -> Show guides

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
    <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)

2. Show Ruler. This option is found under View -> Show Ruler
3. Drag two horizontal guides and two vertical guides. Measure out their spacing on the ruler
4. Enable Snap to Guide. This option is found under View -> Snap to -> Guide
5. Resize image according to the guides

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-E</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-W</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Ctrl ⌘ E</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl ⌘ W</kbd>(Mac) opens the "Edit guides" dialog. There you can set the exact position of the two guides. Using this and snap-to-guides and a little math, you can set the exact dimensions of images and shapes. Lots of monkey-motion, but it will do what you want.